# postfix for web server

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, postfix

Situation: small (young) company, one root server for web, mail with google apps. Mail to "`foo@example.com`" is sent to google, but webbrowsers are directed to the server (`example.com` and `www.example.com` - the dns has a wildcard entry), which is an ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Now I'd like to be able to send mails from the server (cron messages and others) to this google account (i.e. to `foo@example.com`) but I don't want to open the server as a spam relay. How should I set `/etc/mailname`? What about `/etc/hosts` and how should I configure postfix? What information should I provide to get better help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure Postfix to send/relay emails Gmail (smtp.gmail.com) via port 587](http://serverfault.com/questions/119278/configure-postfix-to-send-relay-emails-gmail-smtp-gmail-com-via-port-587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a full-fledged MTA for this; it is overkill.

Instead, look at one of the many available nullmailer options such as **ssmtp**.

A nullmailer acts as a local mailserver, but it only sends out, and they can deal with gmail just fine.